# How to make Ionic modal height auto shows all modal content

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am using ionic inside an angular project. I try to make the `ion-modal` auto height, so there will not be extra white space for some modal.

However, after I set the height to auto in css, the modal only show the 2 buttons in `ion-header`, it won't show other `ion-content` anymore. How do I make it so the height is auto but includes the `ion-content`?

The code for the modal inside html is as followed.

```
<ion-modal [isOpen]="openSensor" [backdropDismiss]="false">
    <ng-template>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-buttons slot="start">
                    <ion-button>ButtonA</ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
                <ion-buttons slot="end">
                    <ion-button [strong]="true">ButtonB</ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="ion-padding">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="stacked">Tag</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"  placeholder="Full Name"  [(ngModel)]="fullName"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-content>
    </ng-template> 
</ion-modal>
```

And this is the global style.css file that related to modal

```
ion-modal.stack-modal {
  --box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  --backdrop-opacity: var(--ion-backdrop-opacity, 0.32);
}
ion-modal {
  --height: auto;
  --border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16852#issuecomment-449433452)

Comment: My angular project somehow has no global.scss file so I have to use converter to convert it to css and appply it to the style.css file. However nothing changed... I wrap around the whole coponent with `<div id="inner-content">`, still nothing changes...